# i want to change every single pixel of an img to black exluding transparent python

Tags: python, image, png

I want to edit all the pixels of a PNG image except for the transparent pixels. I have this code:

```
    img_da_maskerare = Image.open("temp.png")
    width = img_da_maskerare.size[0] 
    height = img_da_maskerare.size[1] 
    for i in range(0,width):
        for j in range(0,height):
            data = img_da_maskerare.getpixel((i,j))
            #print(data) #(255, 255, 255)
            if (data[0]!=255 and data[1]!=0 and data[2]!=0):
                img_da_maskerare.putpixel((i,j),(00, 00, 00))
    img_da_maskerare.show()
```

example: [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow40z.png)  becomes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivCre.png)

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: transparent pixel should has four values `(R,G,B,A)` but you have only `(R,G,B)`. Maybe your file doesn't have transparent pixels. OR maybe you means `background pixels` or `white pixels`

Comment: maybe you should use `==` instead of `!=` because with `!=` probably all pixels match to your expression. Maybe use `print()` inside `if` to see `data` which match to `!=`

Comment: The code is working fine for transparent images

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question. Why is this result incorrect? What should it look like instead? Why?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `if (data[0]!=255 and data[1]!=0 and data[2]!=0):`, what do you think this means? how do you think it works? What do you think `data[0]`, `data[1]` and `data[2]` represent?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` represnts the RGB values,

Comment: Okay, and why should the RGB values tell you anything about whether a pixel is transparent or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `if data[3] == 255`

The `data` has a length of `4` representing the `RGBA`. Where `A` alpha represents the opacity of the pixel. which has values from `0` to `255`. `0` means completely transparent, and `255` means completely opaque.
Here, I used `data[3] > 200` to include those pixels too that have slight transparency.

The code code changes
[image] to [image]

```py
# import PIL module
from PIL import Image
  
img_da_maskerare = Image.open("temp.png")
width = img_da_maskerare.size[0] 
height = img_da_maskerare.size[1] 
for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,height):
        data = img_da_maskerare.getpixel((i,j))

        # RGBA = Red, Green, Blue, Alpha
        #  Alpha = 0 = transparent, 255 = opaque
        # alpha > 200 means almost opaque
        if data[3] >= 200:
            img_da_maskerare.putpixel((i,j),(00, 00, 00))

img_da_maskerare.save('temp_maskerad.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over images in Python with `for` loops should only be a very last resort - it is *slow*, *error-prone* and *inefficient*.

Try to favour built-in functions that are programmed in optimised `C` or vectorised **Numpy** functions.

Essentially, you seem to want an image that is black anywhere the original image is opaque. So, let's be guided by that:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load image
im = Image.open('Ow40z.png')

# Extract the alpha channel and threshold it at 200
alpha = im.getchannel('A')
alphaThresh = alpha.point(lambda p: 255 if p>200 else 0)

# Make a new completely black image same size as original 
res = Image.new('RGB', im.size)

# Copy across the alpha channel from original
res.putalpha(alphaThresh)
res.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Just FYI, that takes 337 microseconds versus 166 milliseconds for your loop-based approach, i.e. it is around 500x faster, and there are no loops and indices to get wrong.

---

I mentioned you can use **Numpy** so here is much the same thing done using that:

```
import numpy as np

# Open image and make into Numpy array
na = np.array(Image.open('Ow40z.png'))

# Make every pixel, of every row of every column black in RGB channels, i.e. channel 0, 1, 2
na[:, :, :3] = 0

# Make Boolean True/False mask of all alphas > 200
mask = na[:,:,3] > 200

# Set alpha channel to 255 wherever mask is True, and 0 elsewhere
na[:, :, 3] = mask * 255

# Convert back from Numpy array to PIL Image
pilImage = Image.fromarray(na)
```